# Laravel: on Model::all() set parameter to model method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to set a parameter to each model method when calling Model::all().

Model:

```
protected $appends = ['convertedImage'];

public function getconvertedImageAttribute(String $logo_base64) {
    //actions here
}
```

View:

```
<script>
    var logo_base64 = '...logo_string_to_base_64...';
    var allFrames = '{!! \App\Model::all()->toJson() !!}';
</script>
```

My question is how to set logo_base64 from view as parameter to Model method getconvertedImageAttribute() on calling Model::all();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you must add static setter to set logo_base64 to your model:

```
public static function setLogoStringToBase64($value) {
   self::$logoStringToBase64 = $value;
}
```

Also, adding static variable to your \App\Model class.
Then, in your front-end part you assign you value:

```
 \App\Model::setLogoStringToBase64(your_value)
```

And then you must re-write you attribute like this:

```
protected $appends = ['converted_image'];
```

`public function getConvertedImageAttribute() {
    //actions here with your variable self::$logoStringToBase64
}`

Note the capital letter "C" in ConvertedImageAttribute.
That's all.

Also, you can override toJson method of your model. But i think, it's not correct.